# Deploy a flash application with Heroku

Tags: facebook, git, facebook-graph-api, heroku, amazon-s3

Some time ago,

i deployed my first flash game on Facebook using the Heroku Server. Of course, i was pushing the swf-game file to the git repository. Unfortunately, my swf file is about 9 mb large and with every new version of the game the git repository grew bigger. Now it is around 300 mb and i can't pull it anymore.

Is there a Way to delete the old versions of the swf file from the repository?

If not, would it be possible to store the swf file on amazons-S3 server and still deploy with heroku?

I already read the [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3) on the Heroku website, made an S3 account and stored the keys as "application config vars", but i am far from making it work, because i dont understand how to connect S3 with Heroku.

Or maybe i am doing it all wrong and there is a simple solution for my problem?

So any help is highly(!) appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If are just embedding the SWF on a page and you're app doesn't need to actually interact with S3 at runtime, you should need to do anything with keys in your app. Instead, just upload the SWF to S3, make it publicly accessible, and put the link to it in your app.

For more information on making the URL public, see *To make an object accessible by everyone* on http://aws.amazon.com/articles/5050.

For example of an embedded SWF hosted on S3, see view-source:http://flashtuts.s3.amazonaws.com/080_DrawingApp/Src/preview.html. Note, this example happens to also have the HTML page hosted on S3, but this could be anywhere, including Heroku. The point is that the embedded object points to S3:

```
<object width="600" height="290" data="http://flashtuts.s3.amazonaws.com/080_DrawingApp/Src/DrawingApp.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
```

Comment: Hi Ryan, thank you very much for the input. I tried what you suggested (The html-wrapper on heroku and the large swf file on S3) and the embedding worked. Unfortunately, the facebook authentification is handled in the swf file and it seems like that the swf can't connect to facebook anymore.